# Grub Error after installing Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.04, grub2, 12.10, data-recovery

I received a GRUB error after upgrading my perfectly working Ubuntu 12.04 installation to 12.10. The machine is a fairly new Toshiba C640 Satellite laptop. Ubuntu was the only OS on it.

The solution being suggested is to reinstall 12.04 which is unacceptable, as I have a lot of docs and files in my home folder which I can't lose. Is there a way to perform a rollback or reinstall without losing my files and settings? If not, why was 12.10 released when it doesn't work? Just curious.

Comment: Solution being suggested where? Also, Ubuntu 12.10 works just fine, your issue is just a corrupted bootloader, which is pretty easily fixed without reinstalling your OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could download and burn this disc, Ubuntu Secured Remix,
It is also a live cd where you can boot it from the cd and then use Boot-Repair to repair GRUB.
Hope this helps

[ubuntu secured remix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ubuntu-secured/)

Answer (score 1):

Follow method Tested and work 100%
1)Boot with USB or Live CD
2)sudo apt-get remove --purge grub-pc grub-common grub (to remove the packages and config files)
3)sudo apt-get install grub-pc (it installs all needed files)
4)sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
5)sudo apt-get install boot-repair 
6)boot-repair (follow it step by step for Install new bootloader by select Recommended option )
Enjoy Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

If grub is broken, you can fix that with [Resc-a-tux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/).

This is a live cd with a primary goal: Restoring grub/installing grub. It's a nice live cd which I used after windows just removed my grub without asking, and it worked like a charm.

> **Rescatux features:**
>
> Fixes GRUB and GRUB2
>
> Regenerates Debian/Ubuntu grub menues
>
> Check and fix filesystems
>
> Fixes Windows MBR
>
> Blank Windows passwords
>
> Boot Info Script
>
> Change Gnu/Linux password
>
> Regenerate sudoers file
>
> **Extra tools:**
>
> Synaptic
>
> Gparted 0.7

Answer (score -1):

Re the re-installation of GRUB, I found this solution great.
http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-restore-grub-2-after-reinstalling-windows-xpvistawin7

The site takes you through the steps to install Boot repair from your live boot, and this is quite smooth. I've used it a couple of times messing around with my home PC - wife and kids were thrilled to bits when they got their installation back :)

Re docs and other settings, I have found a nifty way to future-proof this. Learned it from a friend.
When you partition the system for installing windows,(or even just for Ubuntu) keep

(1) a 15 GB partition separately for the system folder "/" ,

(2) A separate partition equal to 2-times-the RAM for SWAP, and

(3) A separate "/home" partition. This way, whenever you want to update your Ubuntu version, all you need to do while installing, is to select "something else" during the partitioning process. Mark this 15 GB and format as Ext4, use this partition as   "/". Mark this  partition to be formatted.

Now is the best part.

Mark the existing /home partition that you are already using to be mounted as "/home" but DO NOT FORMAT IT. (that is, don't check the "format" box)
Make sure that you give the existing user name and password when installing the new version . This way, once you reinstall,your system will be installed (old one will be deleted, of course) and your entire home folder will remain as it is. Not only that, much to my pleasant surprise, even my addons, bookmarks, saved passwords - everything was fully intact.

You will need to however, update the software, and reinstall all the other software / packages that you want, once again , since the new one will not be compatible.

You could also try to google for "aptoncd" which is a programme used to backup your existing installation packages, and this can be re-installed on your other computer  (or friend's Comp) running the same version of Ubuntu so you don't need to download the packages each time. You will have to select these packages from the Ubuntu Software Centre. It will not download these packages.

Hope this helps - at least for the future.
(I did exactly this - had to go back to 12.04 after installing 12.10)

Yash